# Sonar : Analyze AnguarJS code with Plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have configured sonar to analyze java script code with sonar-scanner. It works fine. But how to analyze AngularJS code? Is there any plugin available?

Comment: What do you mean by "AngularJS code"?

Comment: Maybe best practice for angulars js controller, services & factory. 
Like a "controller as"-syntax or a check of used bindings vs. needed bindings. Templates which could be extracted to components or directives would be also very nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about using SonarQube with AngularJs code (TypeScript/JS/CSS/HTML) ([Supported Types](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.9/analyzing-source-code/languages/javascript-typescript-css/#supported)), current SonarQube 9.9 LTS supports it. See [Link](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.9/analyzing-source-code/languages/javascript-typescript-css/)
You can develop your own QualityGate or use the default one as per the package.